# How to sort on column not part of select statement in spring JPA specification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

My table structure is as follows:

```
TractorEntity {
  List<SegmentEntity>
}

SegmentEntity {
  List<SegmentTrailerEntity>
}

SegmentTrailerEntity {
  TrailerNumber
}
```

I need to sort TractorEntity based on trailerNumber stored in segmentTrailerEntity, using spring JPA specifications.

Due to one to many relation, the data gets duplicated several times. Issue is, if I add a **DISTINCT** clause , then its expect the column trailerNumber to be part of **SELECT** statement.

> Error : expression #1 of order by clause is not in select list

So I removed the distinct keyword and just used joins to pull the data :

```
Path trailerPath = root.join(TractorEntity_.segmentEntities, JoinType.LEFT)
                                .join(SegmentEntity_.segmentTrailers, JoinType.LEFT)
                                .get(SegmentTrailerEntity_.trailer.getName());
```

Issue with this approach is, the total count value also considers duplicate records, like there are 20 unique records and 6 duplicate records, which leads to incorrect total count. I can remove the duplicates in java, but total count is still incorrect.

Then as per research on Google, I tried to select the columns ( using fetch) on joined table, which works upto 1 level :

```
Fetch bFetch = root.fetch(TractorEntity_.segmentEntities, JoinType.INNER);
Join<TractorEntity_, SegmentEntity_> bJoin = (Join<TractorEntity_, SegmentEntity_>) bFetch;
orders.add(criteriaBuilder.asc(bJoin.get(SegmentEntity_.trip.getName())));
//works
```

But when I tried this approach for current problem , it failed :

```
orders.add(root.fetch(TractorEntity_.segmentEntities, JoinType.INNER).fetch(SegmentEntity.segmentTrailers, JoinType.INNER).get(SegmentTrailer_.trailerNumber)));
```

Error :

> "MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags"

Then I tried to join two tables and try fetch only on the last table :

```
ListJoin segmentEntityJoin = root.join(TractorEntity_.segmentEntities, JoinType.INNER);
Fetch bFetch = segmentEntityJoin.fetch(SegmentEntity_.segmentTrailers, JoinType.INNER);
Join<SegmentEntity_, SegmentTrailerEntity_> bJoin = (Join<SegmentEntity_, SegmentTrailerEntity_>) bFetch;

orders.add(criteriaBuilder.asc(bJoin.get(SegmentTrailerEntity_.trailer.getName())));
```

This approach also failed with error :

Error :

> query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched
> association was not present in the select list

Please let me know, if anything else can be tried to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

JPA generates and SQL statement and ORDER BY is done in memory by the database AFTER the data has been selected.

So you can ONLY sort by a column that is present in the result.

Comment: using single fetch join, adds all the columns in select, from joined tables. But I am unable to use fetch join 2 times. Is there a limitation?

Comment: Yes that's a limitation of Hibernate. If you use Set instead of List it will work

Comment: Issue is , its forms cartesian product and degrade performance. I will update my team, regarding the limitation.